# NetBeans Laravel View Xdebug

Tags: laravel, netbeans, xdebug

Xdebug working fully on breakpoints in the controller, however when set in the view they are ignored.

What do I need to configure to do this seemingly simply requirement?
Obviously to work on Controllers shows it's configured correctly.

I guess its something to do with Laravel caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the `storage/framework/views` folder, then set your breakpoint in that file. The view that you're looking at is compiled with Blade and not interpreted and therefore x-debug cannot observe breakpoints set in it.

Comment: Okay great thats what I thought - I have a platform specific cfg external to laravel so can I run a laravel function to disable config/cache at runtime if on a dev server. I think to interpret laravel individual compiled views is impracticle

Comment: @DataMechanics I don't disagree with you on that front; best of luck.

Comment: I have never edited core Laravel code and discourage it as could be overwritten during upgrades - can anyone advise of a function to do this that is built into laravel

Comment: @DataMechanics The thing is that you can't stop blade from compiling the PHP code. You can have the view deleted in a terminable fashion; but I don't personally know of a way to stop the compiling all together.

Comment: hmm maybe something here anyone,by class override - https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/View/Compilers.html